# Sorting multidimensional arrays in c++ using STL methods

Tags: c++

i was wondering if there are any means by which we can sort multidimensional arrays using STL in c++. i wanted to try using STL methods because they will be best in competitions instead of writing our own sorting algorithm. i tried a pseudo-code which is buggy and i don't know how to handle the error.

```
int a[n][n];

//read values into array

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
sort(a[i][0],a[i][n]);
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [std::sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) and [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)

Comment: your upper bound should be a[i][n-1]...

Comment: You want to sort every array in separate? Or would you have to change values (sort) between arrays?

Comment: What does it ever mean to sort a multidimensional array?

Answer (score 3):

It depends how you want to sort. First of all, I would recommend using `std::vector`. Then use `std::sort`. By default, it will sort by the first element of each vector. See the following example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> a = {{1,5,4,3},
                                       {2,5,1,4},
                                       {1,1,6,2}};

    std::sort(begin(a), end(a));  // Sort a by the first element of each vector

    for (auto& line : a)   // Loop over each inner vector
    {
        for (auto& element : line)  // Loop over each element in current vector
        {
            std::cout << element;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
1162
1543
2514
```

Alternatively, you can go through each vector and sort by it's elements

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> a = {{1,5,4,3},
                                       {2,5,1,4},
                                       {1,1,6,2}};

    for (auto& line : a)   // Loop over each inner vector
    {
        std::sort(begin(line), end(line));  // Sort each vector
        for (auto& element : line)  // Loop over each element in current vector
        {
            std::cout << element;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
1345
1245
1126
```

Comment: Is `auto` just for c++11 or is in all c++ versions? If you want to also do internal sorting do `std::sort(begin(line), end(line));` inside first for loop.

Comment: Yes `auto` is in C++11 and later.

Comment: performance wise it's better to declare `const auto&` (first sample code) in range-for loop when want to process complex objects as `std::vector` and `auto&` (second sample code) when want to modified.

Comment: `for (auto line : a)` will make a copy of the row vector on each iteration which may or may not be what you want. If you were to iterate over the `a` matrix again afterwards, its rows wouldn't be sorted. You can use `for (auto& line : a)` to iterate over the rows directly, causing the `a` matrix to be mutated, and avoiding a potentially expensive copy for large rows. Same goes for the inner `element` loop to a lesser degree since the elements are ints and the copy is trivial.

Comment: Is `auto&` compiled as iterators are (`std::vector<T>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it`)? If not, is it as fast?

Comment: as @NetVipeC said earlier, best practice for using a range-for loop in C++ is to always default to `for (const auto& variable_name : container)` unless you're absolutely sure that you need to mutate the container. In this case, I'd personally use a `const auto& element` for the inner loop since you're not changing the element's value inside the loop. It doesn't really change the semantics of the code, but it's slightly more idiomatic.

Comment: @t.pimentel `auto` would not be `std::vector<T>::iterator`, it actually takes care of dereferencing the iterator, so it would be of type `T` whatever was in the container.

Comment: @t.pimentel, you're basically right. As an extension, the variable `var` in `for (auto& var : v)` would correspond to an iterator dereference. i.e.,  `for (std::vector<T>::iterator it ...) { T& var = *it; ... }`

Answer (score 1):

More generic is to use Boost Multi-Arrays. MultiArrays allow you to specify ranges of all sorts, that you can then feed into std::sort, depending on what subset of the 2D array you want to sort.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html#sec_views

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `sort(a[i][0],a[i][n]);`
use `sort(a[i],a[i]+n);`
it will work.