# Sorting bidimensional arrays by column using STL

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, multidimensional-array

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25610676/sorting-multidimensional-arrays-in-c-using-stl-methods) question, we see a good explanation how sort vectors by the first element of each vector and a second example going through each vector and sort by it's elements.

I know that arrays are not the *first class citizens* of C++ for power users of STL, but I like arrays (just like Andrei Alexandrescu).

So, lets consider the code:

```
typedef int arr2D[3];

arr2D array2D[3] = { { 1, 4, 3 },
                     { 9, 2, 5 },
                     { 7, 6, 8 } };

std::sort(begin(array2D[2]), end(array2D[2]), greater<>());
```

The result of this is, ordering the last **row** of array2D by descending order, like this:

```
1 4 3
9 2 5
8 7 6 <- last row by descending order
```

However, what I want is ordering the last **column** of array2D by descending order, like this:

```
1 4 8
9 2 5
7 6 3
    ^
    └--- last column by descending order
```

Using plain `array`s (not vectors) and `std::sort`, can someone help me ?

Thank you

Comment: Unfortunately you can't sort "columns" using `std::sort`. You can extract them into a separate array (or vector) (so `newArray[0]` corresponds to `array2D[0][2]`, etc), sort that, and write the sorted values back into your array.

Comment: You would have to transpose your matrix, before and after the sort.

Comment: Some programmer dude and Jonas: I thought the same as both of you, but before I read your comments, I thought I was wrong. Now I am sure that `std :: sort` can only be applied to contiguous data structures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a custom iterator, that iterates the elements in specific column, over each row. Something like this:

```
template<class Arr>
using sub_array_t = std::remove_pointer_t<std::decay_t<Arr>>;

template<class Arr>
using column_iterator_base = std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, sub_array_t<sub_array_t<Arr>>>;

template<std::size_t col_index, class Arr>
struct column_iterator : column_iterator_base<Arr>
{
    using parent = column_iterator_base<Arr>;
    using value_type = typename parent::value_type;
    using difference_type = typename parent::difference_type;
    using sub_array = sub_array_t<Arr>;

    Arr* arr;
    sub_array* row;

    column_iterator(Arr* arr)                 : arr(arr), row(*arr) {}
    column_iterator(Arr* arr, sub_array* row) : arr(arr), row(row) {}

    column_iterator begin() {return {arr};}
    column_iterator end()   {return {arr, std::end(*arr)};}

    column_iterator& operator+=(difference_type rhs) {row += rhs; return *this;}
    column_iterator& operator-=(difference_type rhs) {row -= rhs; return *this;}
    value_type& operator*() const {return (*row)[col_index];}
    value_type* operator->() const {return (*row) + col_index;}
    value_type& operator[](difference_type rhs) const {return row[rhs][col_index];}

    column_iterator& operator++() {++row; return *this;}
    column_iterator& operator--() {--row; return *this;}
    column_iterator operator++(int) {column_iterator tmp(arr, row); ++row; return tmp;}
    column_iterator operator--(int) {column_iterator tmp(arr, row); --row; return tmp;}

    difference_type operator-(const column_iterator& rhs) const {return row-rhs.row;}
    column_iterator operator+(difference_type rhs) const {return column_iterator(arr, row+rhs);}
    column_iterator operator-(difference_type rhs) const {return column_iterator(arr, row-rhs);}
    friend inline column_iterator operator+(difference_type lhs, const column_iterator& rhs)
    {return column_iterator(rhs.arr, lhs+rhs.row);}
    friend inline column_iterator operator-(difference_type lhs, const column_iterator& rhs)
    {return column_iterator(rhs.arr, lhs-rhs.row);}

    bool operator==(const column_iterator& rhs) const {return row == rhs.row;}
    bool operator!=(const column_iterator& rhs) const {return row != rhs.row;}
    bool operator> (const column_iterator& rhs) const {return row >  rhs.row;}
    bool operator< (const column_iterator& rhs) const {return row <  rhs.row;}
    bool operator>=(const column_iterator& rhs) const {return row >= rhs.row;}
    bool operator<=(const column_iterator& rhs) const {return row <= rhs.row;}
};

template<std::size_t col_index, class Arr>
auto make_column_iterator(Arr* arr)
{
    return column_iterator<col_index, Arr>(arr);
}


int main()
{
    // array2D = ...
    auto foo = make_column_iterator<1>(&array2D);
    std::sort(foo.begin(), foo.end());
}
```

A lot of the boilerplate for a custom iterator can probably be avoided by using something from boost.

Note: This was written quickly, and may contain errors and unnecessarily convoluted code.

Comment: I appreciate your effort but, as you said, it has errors that I unfortunately can't correct.

Comment: @user7140484 does it not behave as you expected?

Comment: The code don't even compiles, and I can't understand the errors.

Comment: @user7140484 you will need to include the standard headers that are used. And you'll need to add your code that defines `array2D`. Also, I just noticed that you've tagged the question c++11. This code uses a few c++14 features (`std::remove_pointer_t`, `std::decay_t`, `auto` return type), so you'll need to port those to c++11 if your compiler doesn't support the current standard.

Comment: Oh probably thats the reason of some errors, because one error is exactly about `auto return type` . The compiler says `error C3551: expected a trailing return type` and I even don't know what `std::remove_pointer_t` and `std::decay_t` mean. If you can rewrite a C++11 version of the code, I'll tagged as accepted answer (if it works).

Comment: Did you try replacing the auto with `column_iterator<col_index, Arr>`?

Comment: BINGO!!!! Thats the source of the error! One little note: your code orders both 2nd column (ascending) and 3rd column (descending). But it's an acceptable solution (even the code being HUGE). One last question: Do we need ALL the code you wrote? It seems that a big part of the code is dead code. Am I right?

Comment: @user7140484 it's huge but *reusable* :) Do you mean that `column_iterator<1, arr>` touches the third column as well? That  is quite an unexpected side effect, which suggests that there is a bug somewhere in my code. I'll investigate when I have time, but if you can find it, I'd appreciate id you share your findings.

Comment: I don't dare to touch your code. For me is easiest to read hieroglyphs.